# turn based game score recording

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm developing a very, very basic turn-based game using `php` and `jquery` and I'm looking at two different ways of keeping track of the current user's score:

1) `global javascript variables` - for example `var currentScore` at the beginning of the js. The game action and turns are all controlled via ajax so I don't have to worry about a page refreshing losing the variable data.

2) `mysql` - create a row with `currentScore`, `user`, etc and access it / update it every turn.

I'm trying to balance a) load speed and b) making the score tamper-proof. I'm thinking that local javascript would be fast and less load time but mysql records would be more tamper-proof. Does anyone have any advice as to which is faster and which is more tamper-proof, or perhaps have another way of accomplishing this that I didn't list above?

Comment: Go for mysql, seriously I doubt 1 row is going to slow the game down

Comment: Can't you keep a copy of the score in mysql, then when an ajax call is made to your php scripts, you can validate the score?

Comment: Tyzoid, thanks but the point of my question is more which (between php/mysql or some third alternative I'm not thinking of) is the best. It sounds like your vote is for mysql as well?

Comment: You could make the score a local var rather than global and use a get / set method pair... should make it more tamper proof and keep it local and fast... I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your game in PHP, not in JS.

What I mean to say is instead of allowing the player's computer to control the action, and send the results back to the server...

that allows for people to hijack and send messages to your PHP like auto-firing pistols...
...or headshot scripts  ...or speed-hacking.

...or even worse -- sending in messages like: "I just scored 500 points on my turn", and having your PHP script go: "Okay!".

So instead, the core of the game engine should run in PHP, the client should just say: "My character wants to move `X` squares.", and then the server can say: "No, you're a cheating tool, you can only move 3 squares.", and then the client will have to adhere to those rules.

In this regard, PHP will be 100% in control of the score-keeping.

Answer (score 2):

any data that is not stored on the server will be tamperable. any data sent to the server can be doctored. not only should the server store all of the game data, but it should be validating all incoming data from the client. for instance, do the rules actually allow this player to use the move they are telling me they are using? Otherwise, it will be fairly easy to cheat. Then again, your project may not require that amount of scrutiny.

Answer (score 1):

both, 
never trust javascript in games. There will always be a clever player which will mess with it.
Use javascript for the gui part and controlling the game, but always check ALL results in PHP, especially player specific values. Check for the right player!!  Else some losers will mess with your game. 
Don't worry about speed, just script your game (of course with speed and data in mind) and investigate when you hit performance problems. One issue is important from beginning: think about your database tables and queries. That will become most likely your performnce bottleneck,more then bad php scripting.